# After Insert Trigger not working as Expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a scenario
to Insert a record in second table after only when inserting a record in first table on certain conditions.

I have my trigger logic like

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgname_TR AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON <table1> 
DECLARE
v_value NUMBER(12,0);

BEGIN
select br.value into v_value
from table3 BR
where br.value =:NEW.value
and br.category IN (839,23,30,843,1414)
and br.efctv_to_date is null;
IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN 
INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,created_date,updated_date)
VALUES
(1,v_value,SYSDATE,:NEW.LAST_UPDATE_DATE);
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'NO SUCH SOURCES EXISTS');
END;
```

The problem is when I try inserting record in first table on condition `IN (839,23,30,843,1414)`
insert working fine and record gets inserted in second table

on when trying insert other than this  condition `IN (839,23,30,843,1414)`

```
ORA-20001: NO SUCH SOURCES EXISTS
ORA-06512: at "table", line 23
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'table'
```

Comment: What is `CHECK_MIGRATION`?

Comment: that is internal table to check logs

Comment: A TABLE is a table and cannot be `FALSE`

Comment: thats a condition I can also remove that

Comment: Are you saying that a matching row exists in table3 but the exception is raised anyway? Otherwise the error message appears to be correct. By the way, I recommend formatting code for readability

Answer (score 0):

There is a Select into command that, when IN list changed, does not fetch any row. Consequence is `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

Check your data and fix the code:

```sql
select br.value into v_value
from table3 BR
where br.value =:NEW.value
and br.category IN (839,23,30,843,1414)
and br.efctv_to_date is null;
```

This command says that you need a **SINGLE** row from `table3` where `table3.value` is equal to the new value of the trigger table AND `table3.efctv_to_date` is Null AND `table3.category` is in the list (this one or changed).

Oracle will return a message and say that there is no such row.

Be careful with this as there could be more than 1 row (because of `IN()` function) resulting with `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception.